# Need some help and suggestions for learning graduate level mathematics:

Tags: education

Econ/Math involved in graduate school is rarely explained linearly through just one text. The material is often sourced from multiple texts and stitched together. And especially when new math is involved this really makes things difficult for me.

The best way I can explain this is imagine learning a concept:
"A-4-B-6-C" where letters A, B and C, are economic and numbers 4, and 6 are mathematic concepts I need to learn.

Of course any math text with teach 4, and 6 only after concepts 1, 2, 3 and 5 linearly. My problem is I actually go through these earlier chapters for clarity and completion.

I've realized I can't do this anymore it simply takes too much time to try to completely cover everything, along with their associated derivations. Does anybody have a method of learning complex mathematics taught in this more ad-hoc manner? Switching texts and reading everything through is just not feasible. I had a professor swear by only doing practice problems and never reading the words. Has anybody done that or have ways they think snippets of material can be learned at a time?